# How to return Error from inside function call?

Tags: javascript

Small JS question. I have the following code in `report` function:

```
this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("here");
    return new Error('Failed with' + error);
});
```

How can I make return `Error` in `report`? As I understand, currently it just return `Error` in `catch` and then it continue running in `report`.

Comment: [`throw new Error();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Comment: Please post the entire `report` function you're talking about. Does it return a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the promise `catch` returns *reject*, you need to either *throw* the error or return a rejected promise:

```
throw new Error('Failed with ' + error);
```

or

```
return Promise.reject(new Error('Failed with ' + error));
```

Then to have `report` report (as it were) that error, it has to return the promise returned by `catch`, or return another promise that is *resolved to* the promise from `catch`. For instance, if `report` is an `async` function, `await` the result from `catch`. If it isn't, *return* that result:

```
return this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("here");t
    throw new Error('Failed with' + error);
});
```

For clarity: You can't make `report` **throw** an error from within that `catch` callback, because `report` has already returned before that callback runs. (Though if `report` is an `async` function, you can write your logic as though it were really throwing the error.)

Comment: I want the code to continue running if `this.httpClient` didn't faild. How can I do it?

Comment: @vesii - If `report` is not an `async` function, attach a fulfillment handler using `.then`. if it is, use `await`. It's hard to be more specific with only the information in the question. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises (or Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*, links in my profile if you're interested ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are just returning an error object. To throw an exception use the `throw` keyword:

```js
this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("here");
    throw 'Failed with' + error
});
```

If you just want to log the error use `console.error()`:

```js
this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("here");
    console.error('Failed with' + error)
});
```