# What is the right way to handle post request fail in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198103/how-to-return-error-from-inside-function-call) was really bad written (sorry for that!) so I'll try to do it right this time. I'm using NodeJS and I wrote the following code:

```
const car_reporter = {
    // Some Code here (Removed to make it clear)

    httpClient : null,

    scriptReport:  function(username, options) { // Some code here (Removed to make it clear)
    },

    APIReport: function(username, options) {
        if (!(this.httpClient)) {
            this.init();
        }
        try {
            if ('car' in options) {
                var reqConfig = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/car',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: {
                        'carName': carName, // global
                        'username': username,
                        'car': options.car
                    }
                };
                this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch(function (error) {
                    throw new Error('Error while posting car\n' + error);
                });
            }
            // OTHER CODE HERE - NOTICE ME :) (Removed to make it clear)
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    },

    report: function (username, options) {
        if (username === null) {
            return new Error('Invalid username');
        }
        if (fs.existsSync(this.script_path)) {
            return this.scriptReport(username, options);
        } else {
            return this.APIReport(username, options);
        }
    },

    init: function() {
        this.httpClient = axios.create({
            baseURL: this.api_url
        });
    }
};

module.exports = car_reporter;
```

The way I call it:

```
function report_car(user_id, car) {
    var options = { car: car };
    var result = car_reporter.report(user_id, options);
    if (result instanceof Error) {
        logger.error(result);
    }
}
```

I want to throw `Error` in `APIReport` if the post failed. But it says: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection`. What is the right way here to handle errors and return `Error` if post request didn't work? I can't do `return this.httpClient(...` because there is other code after that request. I might need add `.then(...` but how do I know that the post failed?

Comment: wrap the report() and APIReport function with a promise (or make it an async function) and when an error occurs call reject(). In your example call use .then() for the output and .catch() to handle the error

Comment: Your error handling should not use `if (result instanceof Error)`, it should use `try`/`catch` or `.catch()`.

Comment: "*I can't do return this.httpClient(... because there is other code after that request.*" -  isn't that code supposed to wait for the http request to finish anyway?

Comment: @Bergi It's another post request. I might need add `await`. Will it solve it?

Comment: Yes, using `async`/`await` would be the right way to do this. But you will need to fix your error handling regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT

This edition is for question in comments.

If you want no waiting, you could just remove `await` keyword, but you will not get the any error message throw from `car_reporter.report`.

```js
async function report_car(user_id, car) {
    var options = { car: car };
    try {
        car_reporter.report(user_id, options);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
}
```

You could try this example.
You will get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error.
And your `catch` block will not be executed.

```js
function test () {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => {
        rej("not good")
    }, 2000))
}

async function main() {
    try {
        test()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Get error");
        console.log(error);
    }
}

main()
```

In this case, you could add `.catch` behind `test()`.

```js
function test () {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => {
        rej("not good")
    }, 2000))
}

async function main() {
    try {
        test().catch((error) => {
            console.log("Get error inside");
            console.log(error)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Get error");
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("done");
}

main()
```

After you execute above code, you will find `done` is printed first. Then `Get error inside` is printed second. We assume you will display some message after `console.log("done")`, but you don't know `test()` if execute successfully or not. **So basically, you could not display message without waiting in the first executing.**

**Unless, you could show message like "processing" to your user first. Then, tell your user this `test()` is successful or not.**

Back to your code. When you remove the `await`, your catch block will not work well. So, you need to add `.catch` behind your `car_reporter.report`.
Then do something with error message in inside `catch` block. You could send a email tell your user this report broken. But, I'm not sure where this program run. If it run with express as api service, polling is also a method.

```js
async function report_car(user_id, car) {
    var options = {car: car};
    try {
        car_reporter.report(user_id, options).then((result) => {
            // send email with this successful result
            // tell your user this report is fine.
        }).catch((error) => {
            // send email with this error message
            // tell your user this report is broken.
        });
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
    // told your user report is still processing.
}
```

### Original Answer

I modify code based on yours.
Because you're using the axios here, I'll use async-await to refactor the code.

I'll first use async-await to refactor usage in `report_car` function.

```js
async function report_car(user_id, car) {
    var options = { car: car };
    var result = await car_reporter.report(user_id, options);
    if (result instanceof Error) {
        logger.error(result);
    }
}
```

Then I need to add try-catch to avoding the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.
Any throw error from `car_reporter.report` will be in the `catch block`.

```js
async function report_car(user_id, car) {
    var options = { car: car };
    try {
        var result = await car_reporter.report(user_id, options);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
}
```

Next, if username is null, there is an error message.
Change it to `throw` instead of `return` because of using async-await outside.
If you use return, it will be treated as a `resolved` promise.
So, use `throw` and make this error happen on the `catch` block outside.

```js
report: function (username, options) {
    if (username === null) {
        throw new Error('Invalid username');
    }
    if (fs.existsSync(this.script_path)) {
        return this.scriptReport(username, options);
    } else {
        return this.APIReport(username, options);
    }
},
```

And you should use `throw` instead of `return` when you're handling the error.
Then you'll get the error in `catch` block of `report_car` function.

```js
APIReport: function (username, options) {
        if (!(this.httpClient)) {
            this.init();
        }
        try {
            if ('car' in options) {
                var reqConfig = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/car',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: {
                        'carName': carName, // global
                        'username': username,
                        'car': options.car
                    }
                };
                const result = await this.httpClient(reqConfig)
                // handle something with result if you need it
                // other code here ...
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // you could custom error message here, and throw to outside
            // like `throw new Error("axios error")`
            console.log(e)
            throw new Error("axios error")
        }
    },
```

But, what happen when there is error in `other code here` at above example.
Maybe you call a non-exist function, it will throw undefined error.
Your catch block also catch it.
In this moment, you will throw `new Error("axios error")` because you customize your error message.

So, problem is here.
How do I tell the different between these error or customize?
You could directly add `catch` in your axios, then customize the error message like following code.

```js
APIReport: function (username, options) {
        if (!(this.httpClient)) {
            this.init();
        }
        try {
            if ('car' in options) {
                var reqConfig = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/car',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: {
                        'carName': carName, // global
                        'username': username,
                        'car': options.car
                    }
                };
                const result = await this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch((error) => {
                    throw new Error("APIReport axios error")
                })
                // handle something with result if you need it
                // other code here ...
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // here, you could throw other customized error message
            // like, throw new Error("APIReport exception") 
            console.log(e)
            throw e;
        }
    },
```

But, if you throw error in axios catch block, node will not execute following code which I mention in `other code here`.

If you want the code continue executing when axios has error, you should use `return` instead of `throw` in axios catch block.
If you want the code not continue executing when axios has error, you should use `throw`.
It depend on situation you want.

The whole code look like this.

```js
const car_reporter = {
    httpClient: null,
    scriptReport: function (username, options) {},
    APIReport: function (username, options) {
        if (!(this.httpClient)) {
            this.init();
        }
        try {
            if ('car' in options) {
                var reqConfig = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/car',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: {
                        'carName': carName, // global
                        'username': username,
                        'car': options.car
                    }
                };
                const result = await this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch((error) => {
                    throw new Error("APIReport axios error")
                })
                // handle something with result if you need it
                // other code here ...
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // here, you could throw other customized error message
            // like, throw new Error("APIReport exception") 
            console.log(e)
            throw e;
        }
    },

    report: function (username, options) {
        if (username === null) {
            throw new Error('Invalid username');
        }
        if (fs.existsSync(this.script_path)) {
            return this.scriptReport(username, options);
        } else {
            return this.APIReport(username, options);
        }
    },

    init: function () {
        this.httpClient = axios.create({
            baseURL: this.api_url
        });
    }
};

module.exports = car_reporter;
```

```js
async function report_car(user_id, car) {
    var options = { car: car };
    try {
        var result = await car_reporter.report(user_id, options);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
}
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you, I gave you the boundary! Also, is it possible to explain how to make it not to wait for the report? Just report the car without waiting and in case of error, display it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite `APIReport` as an async function, where you `await` your outgoing requests and wrap the code in a `try/catch`. If needed you can wrap the error in your custom error and rethrow it. Finally in `report_car` you can also have a `try/catch` where you decide what to do with the error:

```
APIReport: async function(username, options) {
        if (!(this.httpClient)) {
            this.init();
        }
        try {
            if ('car' in options) {
                const reqConfig = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/car',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    data: {
                        'carName': carName, // global
                        'username': username,
                        'car': options.car
                    }
                };
                await this.httpClient(reqConfig);
            }

        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          // here you can wrap the caught error in your custom error
          // you could also have checks here for different status-codes, e.g. 401, 500, etc. and map those to custom errors
          throw new Error('Error while posting car');
        }
    }
```

In your caller you can now do the following:

```
async function reportCar(user_id, car) {
    const options = { car: car };
    try {
      const result = await car_reporter.report(user_id, options);
      // handle result
    } catch(err) {
      // handle error here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to throw every error and then need to catch that error,

`APIReport` function is getting call from the `report` function so need to handle error from the that as well,

so changing code as following (in both function)

```
const car_reporter = {
  // Some Code here (Removed to make it clear)

  httpClient: null,

  scriptReport: function (username, options) {
    // Some code here (Removed to make it clear)
  },

  APIReport: function (username, options) {
    if (!this.httpClient) {
      this.init();
    }
    try {
      if ("car" in options) {
        var reqConfig = {
          method: "post",
          url: "/car",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          data: {
            carName: carName, // global
            username: username,
            car: options.car,
          },
        };
        this.httpClient(reqConfig).catch(function (error) {
          throw new Error("Error while posting car\n" + error);
        });
      }
      // OTHER CODE HERE - NOTICE ME :) (Removed to make it clear)
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  },

  report: function (username, options) {
    try {
      if (username === null) {
        throw new Error("Invalid username");
      }
      if (fs.existsSync(this.script_path)) {
        return this.scriptReport(username, options);
      } else {
        return this.APIReport(username, options);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  },

  init: function () {
    this.httpClient = axios.create({
      baseURL: this.api_url,
    });
  },
};

module.exports = car_reporter;
```

and more you can use async await.